# Display content in popup only clicked div

Tags: php, javascript, html, popup

I have this :

```
<div class="wrapper">
     <div class="left1">
     <div id="position" style="background-color:yellow;border:1px solid black;display:none;width:200px;height:200px;"class="PopupDiv";>Position 1<br>Price x<br>Available on xx-xx-xx<br><a href="http://flibay.com/buy.php";>Buy;</a></div>
             <a href="#" onclick="Popup.show('position','reference','center center',{'constrainToScreen':true});;return false;">Details;</a><br>
        <img src="img/banner_1.jpg">
     </div>
     <div class="left2">
    <div id="position" style="background-color:yellow;border:1px solid black;display:none;width:200px;height:200px;"class="PopupDiv";>Position 2<br>Price x<br>Available on xx-xx-xx<br><a href="http://flibay.com/buy.php";>Buy;</a></div>
             <a href="#" onclick="Popup.show('position','reference','center center',{'constrainToScreen':true,'offsetTop':-200});;return false;">Details;</a><br>
        <img src="img/banner_1.jpg">
     </div>
     <div class="left3">
    <div id="poistion" style="background-color:yellow;border:1px solid black;display:none;width:200px;height:200px;"class="PopupDiv";>Position 3<br>Price x<br>Available on xx-xx-xx<br><a href="http://flibay.com/buy.php";>Buy;</a></div>
             <a href="#" onclick="Popup.show('position','reference','center center',{'constrainToScreen':true,'offsetTop':-200});;return false;">Details;</a><br>
        <img src="img/banner_1.jpg">
     </div>
     <div class="left4">
     <div id="position" style="background-color:yellow;border:1px solid black;display:none;width:200px;height:200px;top:50%;left:50%;margin:-(height/2)px 0 0 -(width/2)px;"class="PopupDiv";>Position 4<br>Price x<br>Available on xx-xx-xx<br><a href="http://flibay.com/buy.php";>Buy;</a></div>
             <a href="#" onclick="Popup.show('position','reference','center center',{'constrainToScreen':true,'offsetTop':-200});;return false;">Details;</a><br>
        <img src="img/banner_1.jpg">
     </div>
     <div class="left5">
    <div id="position" style="background-color:yellow;border:1px solid black;display:none;width:200px;height:200px;"class="PopupDiv";>Position 5<br>Price x<br>Available on xx-xx-xx<br><a href="http://flibay.com/buy.php";>Buy;</a></div>
             <a href="#" onclick="Popup.show('position','reference','center center',{'constrainToScreen':true,'offsetTop':-200});;return false;">Details;</a><br>
        <img src="img/banner_1.jpg">
     </div>
     <div class="left6">
    <div id="position" style="background-color:yellow;border:1px solid black;display:none;width:200px;height:200px;"class="PopupDiv";>Position 6<br>Price x<br>Available on xx-xx-xx<br><a href="http://flibay.com/buy.php";>Buy;</a></div>
             <a href="#" onclick="Popup.show('position','reference','center center',{'constrainToScreen':true,'offsetTop':-200});;return false;">Details;</a><br>
        <img src="img/banner_1.jpg">
     </div>
 </div>
```

It is div centered javascript popups, but if I clicked any of those 6 divs, get in popup onlu content first div with ID "position". How can get content only of those div which I clicked? 
P.S
Javacript popup.js from this link with my modifications `http://www.javascripttoolbox.com/libsource.php/popup/combined/popup.js`

Comment: does this link help: http://www.javascripttoolbox.com/lib/popup/example.php ?

Comment: You need to pass an argument to the function that identifies which element was clicked on (you can pass `this`), and the function has to use that argument to show content related to that element.

Comment: I used that link, yes.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the same `id` for ALL of your divs. An `id` **MUST** be unique across the entire document.

```
<div id="position" style="background- ..snip...
          ^^^^^^--- each of these MUST be unique.
```

Try renaming them `position1`, `position2`, etc...

Duplicate IDs makes for an invalid document, and getElementById() is not going to compensate for YOUR error by returning all the matching elements. It's going to (properly) assume an ID should be unique, and return only the FIRST matching element.

Comment: I did but "position" is determined in next javascript function, which I use with my modification, to create centered div popup object, popup.js

Comment: When I used position1, postion2 I got text in that div but popup div is continually moved to right , centered to the refernece object and in my case it's div which I clicked. I want popup be always in center of page no matter what I clicked and with text in particulary div.

Comment: doesn't matter. you're generating invalid html. this is why you're only ever getting the first item in your popup, no matter what you clicked on.

Comment: I want to create something like chess table with squares which are unique and when I click on box, which is div, I should get in popup position of div, like "position 2, black field or white", which represents chess field color. How to implement this?

Comment: So only problem is now how to put div popup in center of page ALWAYS? No move left, right, down...always on center of page?